# Boolean Expression for two conditions of an element of a list

Tags: java, spring-data-jpa, querydsl, boolean-expression

I'm using QueryDSL here to build a predicate, the problem is that this predicate requires two AND conditions and I'm stuck here because I don't know how I'm gonna apply the second condition.

This is the scenario:

I have an equipment, this equipment belongs to a laboratory and the laboratory has a team. Some members of this laboratory team can register new equipments and some don't, this is defined by a boolean attribute "registerEquipment". So my predicate must have these condidtions:

*A user must be member of a laboratory team and has the attribute "registerEquipment" setted true to see this equipment . I tried the following code:

```java
BooleanExpression registerEquipmentAndTeamMember = QEquipment.equipment.laboratory.team.any().registerEquipment.and(QEquipment.equipment.laboratory.team.any().person.id.eq("AQ88"));
```

But is not working because it's executing a condition of registerEquipment first then the teamMember. I would like to know how could i execute both conditions for a team member at the same time.

Comment: What do you hope to happen by having them execute at the same time / whats the issue of having one part of it execute first?

Comment: @MarcSlothEastman By executing both conditions at the same time it will return correctly to me the people who has registerEquipment true and the members of a laboratory team. If it execute separately it will return people who are from the laboratory team and people who don't registerEquipment. This is the problem...

Comment: Why do you think that that's the problem? Given that both these queries are just a "get"/SELECT type query, they won't affect each other. I would recommend trying the queries separately and post results here

Comment: @MarcSlothEastman Because Because QueryDSL is generating the query with two exists instead of one. For example, instead of checking if the current user is a member of a lab team and registerEquipment=true, QueryDSL checks if there is someone who has registerEquipment=true and then whether the current user is part of the laboratory team. When the correct would be if the current user is part of the lab team and has registerEquipment=true.

Comment: @MarcSlothEastman Just like this where exists (select 1 from equipment.laboratory.team as equipment_laboratory_team_0 where equipment_laboratory_team_0.registerEquipment 
and exists (select 1 from equipment.laboratory.team as equipment_laboratory_team_1 where equipment_laboratory_team_1.person.id = ?1))

Comment: That second comment's query you posted just checks if there is someone with that ID and someone with equipment access, not necessarily same person. I would recommend not using the `.any()`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it. I had to use a JPAExpression. This is the correct code:

```
QEquipment equipment = QEquipment.equipment;
QTeam team = QTeam.team;
QLaboratory laboratory = QLaboratory.laboratory;

Predicate predicate = JPAExpressions
       .selectOne()
       .from(team)
       .where(equipment.laboratory.id.eq(laboratory.id),
              laboratory.id.eq(team.laboratory.id),
              team.registerEquipment.eq(Boolean.TRUE),
              team.person.id.eq(userService.getCurrentId())).exists();
```

Now it's gonna filter at the same time the lab member who has permission to register an equipment.